# How to Load Vaadin Component after Netflix Eureka Registration

Tags: vaadin, netflix-eureka

I have a microservice application with Netflix Eureka and Vaadin.
In the frontend application there is a grid that retrieves its data from the backend application.
But since the frontend ui gets built before the Eureka registration, the application fails to build because it does not find the backend (because it does not know yet that it is supposed to find it on Eureka).

Does anyone know how I can make sure, that the frontend Ui is loaded after the Eureka registration?

Comment: I know nothing about Netflix Eureka, but if there's a way to add a listener for when the registration is complete, you should move the data population logic inside that listener. If there's a chance that the delay is long you might also add some placeholder to inform the user what the delay is about (e.g. a spinner/load bar/some 'loading data' text...).

Comment: If there is no listener, the next option could be to poll the data availability periodically, and once it is, cancel the polling and do the data population.

Comment: Also note that if either listening or polling happens on the server-side, you need to push the changes to the client-side (see https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/advanced/server-push ), otherwise your UI will only get updated upon the next user interaction.